# 3d printer filament type question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[How to choose a right 3D printer filament type?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/410/how-to-choose-a-right-3d-printer-filament-type)

I have also made an edit to this question. I would like to know the difference. So, if it is still too broad, can someone suggest an edit for it?

Answer (score 2):

The question is still very broad and can be opinion based. Someone left a comment below your question stating that your question was related to a [more narrow question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-is-pla-different-from-abs-material?rq=1). I would recommend editing your question to explain your situation a bit more. Here are some good points that you can provide users to make it easier to answer:

- Does your print require specific mechanical properties (ie high strength, heat resistance, electrical conductivity, flexibility, etc.)
- Does your print need to "look pretty"
- What type of 3D printing technology are you wishing to use (FDM, FFF, SLS, etc.)

Answering some of these questions will definitely provide users with more direction as to how to answer your question. As it stands right now, your question will result in the general response: "Well, it depends on what you're trying to make...".

I'm sure that I'm not the only one here that has a few different types of material available at any given point as result of various projects (ABS, PLA, PVA, TPE, etc.).